# Listen for change events in forms: JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I have a form with an id of "wizard" - I only have select elements in this form. This form is in a lightbox using the [JQuery plugin fancybox](http://fancybox.net/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.2.1.js):

I want to know when any of these have been changed using JQuery. How can I do this? I currently have:

```
$('form#wizard select[name=servers], form#wizard select[name=cores]').change(function() {
var channels = parseInt($('form#wizard select[name=servers]').val(), 10) * parseInt($('form#wizard select[name=cores]').val(), 10);
$('#yellow').val(channels);
});
```

*EDIT* - I have the above wrapped in `$(document).ready(function() {...}`

However, it does not work, it does not even get run. I have put alerts in there and they never show up. The above only works when the above is a div that I have removed the display:none from, strange! So I am looking for a different implementation to get around this as I need that lightbox as it is.

I really need help on this.

Thanks all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jQuery `change` function only binds those elements that are present when the domready event fires. If the lightbox plugin you are using is dynamically creating elements, you should be using jQuery's [`live`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live#typefn) function to "bind your handler to all current - and future matched elements".

Change this:

```
$('your selector').change(function() { /* code ... */ });
```

with this:

```
$('your selector').live('change', function() { /* code ... */ });
```

Comment: Awesome! This is working better, but it seems it only accounts for changes once? Is this supposed to happen?

Comment: Actually its working but the span element with id "yellow" doesn't get updated, it gets updated when I close the lightox and repoen it? How can I get it to take effect as soon as a change is made?

Comment: My guess is that the span with id "yellow" gets copied by the lightbox plugin which means that you end up with two (or more) span elements with the same id. Since ids should be unique, jQuery only updates your original (hidden) span. Try using class instead of id.

Comment: Do you mean give it a class yellow and refer to it via the class name?

Comment: Sorry, I am a noob - How do I refer to a class? The same way?

Comment: Ok - it makes a change:    $('span#[class=yellow2]').html(channels); - that worked! :)

Comment: If you have a span with class "yellow" (<span class="yellow">...</span>), you can do $('span.yellow').val(channels);

Comment: Thanks, I used that. But I have another problem, but I have open another question for this! More than welcome to help again on it! :)

Comment: `live` method was removed in jQuery 1.9. See [docs](http://api.jquery.com/live/#typefn) for more information.